# Twilio segment tracking taking long time to POST messages

Tags: sentry, segment-io

Consider:

[image]

Why is the Twilio segment [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request taking longer time to process the information?

Should this be faster? I don't have much information about this, but it makes me wonder: Is the issue with the application or the Twilio segment application itself?

Answer (score -3):

The delay in the Twilio Segment POST request could be due to a variety of factors. Here are a few possibilities:

1. **Network Latency**: The time it takes for data to travel from one point to another can impact the speed of your POST request. This is often influenced by factors outside of Twilio's control, such as the speed of your internet connection or the distance between your server and Twilio's.
2. **Server Response Time**: The speed at which your server processes the POST request and returns a response can also affect the overall time it takes for the request to complete.
3. **Content of the Message**: Twilio monitors messages to prevent content violating the Acceptable Use Policy (AUP). If a message you send has violated the AUP, it will be returned and you will receive an error code which identifies the necessary changes you need to make before sending it again. This process could potentially slow down the delivery of messages. You can read more about this in the [Programmable Messaging API Overview](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api).

To troubleshoot this issue, you could try the following steps:

1. Check your server's response time to see if it's causing the delay.
2. Test your network latency by sending a simple POST request and measuring the time it takes to receive a response.
3. Review the content of your messages to ensure they comply with Twilio's AUP.

Remember, the issue could be a combination of these factors, so it might be helpful to investigate all of them.

If you have ongoing concerns or require further assistance, please don’t hesitate to reply, and I'll try to assist you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy - it really isn't helpful if Twilio are sending their employees here to copy-paste ChatGPT answers